# Set Hyperlink Through Code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to set-up VBA syntax to create hyperlinks in a few cells.  This is what I have it down to, but I get a debug error of 'invalid procedure call or argument'

This is my syntax that produces the err

```
Public Sub AddHyperlinks()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, 3), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=ws.Cells(i, 3)
Next i
End Sub
```

**Sample Workbook**
[Sample Workbook](http://www.filedropper.com/book1_17)

Comment: Is `ws` the same as `ActiveSheet` when this executes?

Comment: @Comintern - yes, I set ws = ActiveSheet.  Updated code.

Comment: Is this in a loop?  You don't have i defined to be anything.

Comment: @Rdster - copy paste error.  Full syntax now showing.

Comment: Is the `For i = 2 To lr` correct?  If so, where is `lr` declared and set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextToDisplay does need to be a string. Using CStr (convert to string) will take care of that.

```
TextToDisplay:=CStr(ws.cells(i, 3))
```

After making that change, this tests successfully with your sample workbook.

Answer (score 2):

The `TextToDisplay` parameter of [HyperLinks.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx) is type `Variant`. That means when you pass it a `Range` object with `ws.Cells(i, 3)`, the default member (`.Value`) doesn't get called.  This causes the invalid parameter error as the function expects a `Variant` of subtype `String`.  You need to explicitly call `.Value`:

```
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, 3), Address:="", _
                  SubAddress:="'" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "'!A1", _
                  TextToDisplay:=ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
```

Note that when you use named arguments, you're using a late-bound call to an early-bound interface. This is better:

```
ws.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(i, 3), vbNullString, "'" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "'!A1", _
                  , ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
```

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - I can't replicate. Do you have empty cells in the target columns?

Comment: No empty cells.  column B contains text, and column C contains numbers.